# Perl: renaming doesn't work for $value filename

Tags: perl

I want to fill the folder with copies of the same file that would be called differently. I created a `filelist.txt` to get filenames using Windows `cmd` and then the following code:

```
use strict;    # safety net
use warnings;  # safety net
use File::NCopy qw(copy);

open FILE, 'C:\blabla\filelist.txt';
my @filelist = <FILE>;
my $filelistnumber = @filelist + 1;
my $file = 0;
## my $filename = 'null.txt';
my $filename = $filelist[$file];


while( $file < $filelistnumber ){

    copy('base.smp','temp.smp');
    rename 'temp.smp', $filename;

    $file = $file + 1;

};
```

If I try renaming it into 'test.smp' or whatever, it works. If I try the code above, I get this:

```
Use of uninitialized value $filename in print at blablabla/bla/bla.pl line 25, <FILE> line 90.
```

What am I doing wrong? I feel there's some kind of little mistake, a syntax mistake probably, that keeps evading me.

Comment: Have you printed out all the variables?  Especially the array?  Does it hold what you expected it to hold?  You didn't actually test that the file was opened successfully (add `or die` after the open, preferably with a suitable message).  I'm mildly curious why you don't simply use `copy('base.smp', $filename);` too.

Comment: Having indented the error message, you don't get to line 90 on a file you failed to open, so that isn't the problem. Do you have a blank line at the end of the file? The message quotes line 25 and a `print` operation; you've not got 25 lines of code in the question or a `print` — so we're being asked to debug code we can't see.  That's not sensible.  Please make sure you create an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) and show us the error message from exactly the code you show. How many files do you think were in the directory?

Comment: Jonathan Leffler, yes, i tried printing the stuff, everything was fine. As for copying, it didn't work with the $value in the same way if i remember it correctly, so i tried copying and renaming. Didn't help, heh.

Comment: About the other thing - yeah, i deleted all the prints i used to test this, sorry for the number being a bit wrong and now when i think of it, it does indeed talk about print. I will need to check it again. As for the file number, it was 90.

Comment: It was indeed the blank space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should avoid using bareword file handles. When opening you should open using a file reference like and make sure you catch it if it fails:

```
open(my $fh, '<', 'C:\blabla\filelist.txt') or die "Cannot open filelist.txt: $!";
```

The $fh variable will contain your file reference.

For your problem it looks as though your filelist.txt must be empty. Try using Data::Dumper to print out your @filelist to determine it's contents.

```
use Data::Dumper;
```

EDIT:

Looks like you are also wanting to be setting the $filename variable to the next one in the list for each iteration, so put `$filename = $filelist[$file];` at the beginning of your loop.

Your problem could be that you are looping too far? Try getting rid of the `+ 1` in `my $filelistnumber = @filelist + 1;`

Comment: The file list has 90 lines in it; it's on the 90th line that the problem occurs.  But I agree about avoiding bare-word file handles.

Comment: Try my edit. Looks like you may be reading a line that contains nothing? To avoid going outside the side of the size of an array use a for loop "for my $i (0..$#array) { }"

Comment: I'll try this, yes, thanks. TBH i was already doing $filename = $filelist[$file]; at the beginning of loop, but i accidentially removed it from the file when copying code here. And yeah, i'll try getting rid of +1 since the last line it tries to read is probably blank as Jonathan suggested. That's a nice for and i'll try it, too.

Answer (score 3):

First, here's some improved code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy;

while (<>) {
    chomp;
    copy('base.smp', $_) or die $!;
}
```

You'll save it as `script.pl` and invoke it like this:

```
$ perl script.pl C:\blabla\filelist.txt
```

In what ways is this code an improvement?

- It uses the core module [File::Copy](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::Copy) instead of the deprecated [File::NCopy](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::NCopy).
- It uses the [null filehandle](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2FO-Operators) or "diamond operator" (`<>`) to implicitly iterate over a file given as a command line parameter, which is simple and elegant.
- It handles errors in the event that `copy()` fails for some reason.
- It doesn't use a `while` loop or a C-style `for` loop to iterate over an array, which are both prone to off-by-one errors and forgetting to re-assign the iterator, as you've discovered.
- It doesn't use the old 2-argument syntax for `open()`. (Well, not explicitly, but that's kind of beyond the scope of this answer.)

> What am I doing wrong? I feel there's some kind of little mistake, a
>   syntax mistake probably, that keeps evading me.

A syntax error would have resulted in an error message saying that there was a syntax error. But since you asked what you're doing wrong, let's walk through it:

```
use File::NCopy qw(copy);
```

This module was last updated in 2007 and is marked as deprecated. Don't use it.

```
open FILE, 'C:\blabla\filelist.txt';
```

You should use the three-argument form of [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html), use a lexical filehandle, and always check the return values of system calls.

```
my @filelist = <FILE>;
```

Rarely do you need to slurp an entire file into memory. In this case, you don't.

```
my $filelistnumber = @filelist + 1;
```

There's nothing inherently wrong with this line, but there is when you consider how you're using it later on. Remember that arrays are 0-indexed, so you've just set yourself up for an out of bounds array index. But we'll get to that in a second.

```
my $filename = $filelist[$file];
```

You would typically want to do this assignment inside your loop, lest you forget to update it after incrementing your counter (which is exactly what happened here).

```
while( $file < $filelistnumber ){
```

This is an odd way to iterate over an array in Perl. You could use a typical [C-style `for` loop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#For-Loops), but the most Perlish thing to do would be to use a [`foreach`-style loop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Foreach-Loops):

```
for my $element (@array) {
    ...
}
```

Each element of the list is localized to the loop, and you don't have to worry about counters, conditions, or array bounds.

```
copy('base.smp','temp.smp');
```

Again, always check the return values of system calls.

```
rename 'temp.smp', $filename;
```

No need to do a `copy` *and* a `rename`. You can copy to your final destination filename the first time. But if you *are* going to rename, always check the return values of system calls.

```
};
```

Blocks don't need to be terminated with a semicolon like [simple statements](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsyn.html#Simple-Statements) do.

Comment: Thanks, that's some very solid advice i plan to use later on.